# Quartz.net cron triggers for certain timezones not working

Tags: masstransit, quartz.net

I'm using masstransit.quarts library with .NET Core to schedule some jobs that would fall under different timezones. What I'm observing is, the scheduled jobs get triggered for certain timezone and not for the others.

Following is how I use the masstransit library to schedule the job:

```
 public async Task ScheduleRecurringMessage<T>(string destinationAddress, string scheduleId, string scheduledGroupId, string timeZoneId, DateTimeOffset startTime, DateTimeOffset? endTime, string cronExpression, T message) where T : class
    {
        var destinationUri = string.Format("rabbitmq://{0}/{1}.{2}", eventbusConfig.Value.EventBusUri, eventbusConfig.Value.EventBusEndpointName, destinationAddress);

        var recurringSchedule = new MasstransitRecurringSchedule(timeZoneId, startTime, endTime, scheduleId, scheduledGroupId, cronExpression);
        await sendEndpoint.ScheduleRecurringSend<T>(new Uri(destinationUri), recurringSchedule, message);
    }
```

However, when I check the [QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS] table, I can see that all scheduled jobs get correctly recorded here, against the correct timezone. However, UTC- timezones (e.g. EST), the scheduler doesnt trigger the event to Rabbitmq.

Can anyone help me identity why this is happening?